# Why Honda civic 2002 ex shuts off at 100km/h?

Tags: honda, civic

My Honda civic 2002 auto gets shut off when ever I cross 100 km/h, it doesn't over heat, radiator and fans are working properly.  any reason for that?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! At what RPM are you at when you hit 100 km/h? Is this in *any* gear or just 5th gear? What I'm wondering is if this might be connected with the VTEC portion of the engine. VTEC kicks in around 4000 RPM, which is rather high (my '03 Civic rarely sees that high of RPM), but depending on how you are driving your Civic, you may get to that RPM level.